# Deriving the Berry phase from the Schroedinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Let $|n(\mathbf{R})\rangle$ be eigenstates of the snapshot Hamiltonian $H|\mathbf{R} \rangle$, of eigenvalues $E_n(\mathbf{R})$. The vector $\mathbf{R}$ contains the parameters upon which the system depends. The objective is to solve the Schroedinger equation $i | \dot{\psi}(t) \rangle = H(\mathbf{R}(t)) |\psi(t)\rangle$ when the parameter vector $\mathbf{R}(t)$ varies slowly with time.  Consider the trial solution
$$\begin{align*}
|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{i\gamma_n(t)} e^{-i\phi_n(t)} |n(\mathbf{R}(t))\rangle
\end{align*}$$

with $\phi_n(t) = \displaystyle{\int}_{0}^t E_n(\mathbf{R}(t')) dt'$. I obtain (omitting functional dependencies for clarity)
$$\begin{align*}
|\dot{\psi}\rangle &= e^{i\gamma_n } e^{-i\phi_n}(i\dot{\gamma}_n |n\rangle - i \dot{\phi}_n |n\rangle+ |\dot{n}\rangle ) \\
&= e^{i\gamma_n} e^{-i\phi_n }(i\dot{\gamma}_n |n\rangle - i E_n |n\rangle+ |\dot{n}\rangle )
\end{align*}$$
so putting $|\dot{\psi}\rangle = -iH |\psi \rangle = -iE_n e^{i\gamma_n} e^{-i\phi_n} |n\rangle$ gives
$$\begin{align*}
|\dot{n}\rangle = -i\dot{\gamma}_n |n\rangle
\end{align*}$$
Now I'm trying to figure out how to solve for $\gamma_n$, which is supposed to be:
$$\begin{align*}
\gamma_n(\mathcal{C}) = \int_{\mathcal{C}} i \langle n(\mathbf{R}) | \nabla_{\mathbf{R}} n(\mathbf{R}) \rangle d\mathbf{R} \ \ \ (\dagger)
\end{align*}$$
I assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is a path in $\mathbf{R}$-space, parameterised by time $t$. That is to say,
$$\begin{align*}
i\gamma_n(t) &= -\int_0^t \langle n(\mathbf{R}(t') | \nabla_{\mathbf{R}(t')} n(\mathbf{R}(t')) \rangle \dot{\mathbf{R}}(t') dt' \\
i\dot{\gamma}_n(t) &= - \langle n(\mathbf{R}(t) | \nabla_{\mathbf{R}(t)} n(\mathbf{R}(t)) \rangle \dot{\mathbf{R}}(t)
\end{align*}$$
From here (again omitting functional depencies for clarity), I'm not totally sure how to show that $i\dot{\gamma}_n |n \rangle = -|\dot{n}\rangle$, so that $(\dagger)$ is indeed a solution of the differential equation. I had the idea to re-write
$$\begin{align*}
| \nabla_{\mathbf{R}} n  \rangle \dot{\mathbf{R}} = |\dot{n} \rangle
\end{align*}$$
so that
$$\begin{align*}
i\dot{\gamma}_n |n \rangle &= - \langle n |\dot{n} \rangle | n \rangle = -| n \rangle \langle n |\dot{n} \rangle
\end{align*}$$
but the RHS doesn't look quite like $|\dot{n}\rangle$, since the identity operator is rather a sum $\displaystyle{\sum_n} | n \rangle \langle n |$ over $n$. Where did I go wrong? For reference, I am following [these notes](https://phyx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/TI/Lecture%20notes/2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\g{\gamma}
\def\d{\delta}
\def\R{{\bf R}}
\newcommand\ket[1]{|#1\rangle}
\newcommand\bra[1]{\langle #1|}
\newcommand\braket[2]{\langle #1|#2\rangle}$The condition that
\begin{align*}
\ket{\dot n} &= -i\dot\g_n\ket{n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
follows as a requirement on our trial solution.
This condition can be satisfied by solving the differential equation (1) for $\g_n$.
Condition (1) implies
\begin{align*} 
\braket{m}{\dot n} &= -i\dot\g_n\braket{m}{n} \\
\braket{m}{\dot n} &= -i\dot\g_n\d_{mn} \\
\dot\g_n &= i\braket{n}{\dot n}. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Thus, for example, $i\dot\g_n\ket{n} = -\ket{n}\braket{n}{\dot n}$ as claimed.
(Note that $\dot\g_n$ is just a $c$-number.)
Multiplying by $\ket{n}$ has not gotten us closer to finding $\g_n$, so we leave this.

From (2) we have
\begin{align*}
\dot\g_n &= i\braket{n}{\dot n} \\ 
&= i\braket{n(\R(t)}{\frac{d}{dt}n(\R(t))} \\
&= i\braket{n(\R(t))}{\nabla_{\R(t)}n(\R(t))\cdot \dot\R(t)} 
    & \textrm{mv chain rule} \\
&= i\braket{n(\R(t))}{\nabla_{\R(t)}n(\R(t))}\cdot\dot\R(t).
    & \textrm{$\R$ a vect of $c$-nums} 
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\g_n(t) &= \int_0^t  i\braket{n(\R(t))}{\nabla_{\R(t)}n(\R(t))}\cdot\dot\R(t) dt \\
&= \int_{\mathcal{C}} i\braket{n(\R)}{\nabla_{\R}n(\R)}\cdot d\R.
\end{align*}

Comment: Got it, thanks! I hadn't realised that the eigenstates $|n\rangle$ are normalised :)

Comment: @JamesW.: Great! I am glad to help.